# How to integrate leaflet into power BI

Tags: typescript, leaflet, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, pbiviz

I want to make a custom visual of power bi with the exact  same benefits  of leaflet.

I know how to implement  leaflet using angular and how to make a custom visual.

But I couldn’t  find any good resource  to integrate lefatlet into power bi since pbiviz  project doesn’t  provide any Index.html file

I am new to this,if my question  is not enough explained, please  let me know